# Clarification on data-parsley-`constraint`-message in Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, parsley.js, parsley

As per the documentation, Parsley allows us to override error messages with the data attribute **data-parsley-`constraint`-message**.

What's not specified, however, is a complete list of constraint names you can use.

The only example we have in the documentation pertains the *required* constraint, but what about all of the other error messages?

Let's say I want to customize the error message for an invalid email (default is 'This value should be a valid email.'): how can I do that with that data attribute?

Where can I find a complete list of all "constraint" names?

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably just look up parsley constraints. It's been a while since I used parsley, but I believe any parsley constraints can have it's message changed like this, even custom validations.

Comment: See this page, look for built-in validators http://parsleyjs.org/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in constraints (aka validators) [are listed in the doc](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#validators)